# docker-compose scale with different cpuset

Tags: docker, docker-compose, scale, cpuset

How can I scale a service but apply a different `cpuset` on each instance with docker-compose ?

For example: I have 4 cpus, I want 4 instances, each using 1 unique cpu.

Answer (score 0):

What version of docker-compose are you using? I'm asking because accomplish what you desire is only possible with docker-compose v2.x or docker-swarm as you can see below.

[image]

you can check more info [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources) in the docker doc.

supposing that you are using docker-compose 2.4, you can define a service like this in your `docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:1.0.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=1234
    cpu_count: 1
    mem_limit: 200m
```

Where `cpu_count` is number o cpu cores you want to use in the service, and `mem_limit` is the limit of memory that your service can consume.

To define the number of replicas you must run:
`docker-compose up --scale redis=2`

Where `redis` is name of the service in the docker-compose and `2` is the number of replicas that you desire. So both the two containers will spin up with 1 core of CPU and 200m of memory.

To check the container resources consumption you can run `docker stats`

Source:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm using docker-compose v3.8. I'm not familiar with swarm yet so I might need to task a deeper look at it.

Comment: After reading the long github thread (https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4513) about the removal of non-swarm config from v3 docker-compose, it turns out that v2 is supposed to be used for non-swarm usage (which doesn't really makes sense but whatever...).

Do you have a solution to my first issue now that I'm using docker-compose v2.4 ?

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope it can be helpful to you.